# FBA site not allowing to reset password

Tags: forms-authentication, iis

we are trying to reset password of a FBA user through IIS site. However it is showing below message

**The user's question and answer are required to reset the password. As a security best practice, users should reset their own passwords by using your Web application.**

Kindly let know how it can be done. And if from web application, from which page

Thank you

Comment: Do you have a custom form to create users?

Comment: Hi ThinkB4Code, i donot have custom form for create users.

Comment: Ok, so you are using FBA to connect the user in your AD? And, is SP farm is configured using same AD?

Comment: We have configured FBA as per normal procedure. All users are able to access sharepoint through FBA login (aspnet db users). except for few. Thus wanted to reset password of user doubting they might have forgot their password. However, IIS is not allowing to do so. 

Kindly advise. Thank you

Comment: If you are comfortable with SQL queries then follow this URL. https://codinglifestyle.wordpress.com/2010/02/13/unlock-user-via-database-query-asp-net-membership/